# How to sign a Dashboard Widget (Dashcode) with Gatekeeper ID

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, dashboard, dashcode, osx-gatekeeper

Does anyone know how to sign a Dashboard widget (OS-X Mountain Lion) that was made by Dashcode with a Gatekeeper ID? All tutorials just go about XCode-Apps or package-installers. Are dashboard-widgets handled like installers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit old, but the question still seems relevant. I figured out how it works, see e.g. my widget at https://maba.wordpress.com/widgets/, tested on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.4).

Here are the steps:

First, you need a production Developer ID of type "Developer ID Application".
Make sure it's imported into your keychain.
Also note its name. Typically it is like *"Developer ID Application: Your Name"*.

Now, use the codesign tool to sign your widget on the command line like this:

```
codesign -f -s "Developer ID Application: Your Name" /Path/to/YourWidget.wdgt
```

You might want to verify using the spctl tool:

```
spctl -a -vvvv /Path/to/YourWidget.wdgt
```

The output should look like this:

```
/Path/to/YourWidget.wdgt: accepted
source=Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: Your Name (XXXXXXXXX)
```

(Answer is a duplicate of my original answer here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/140973)